# Vue invalid host header

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli-3

Don't know why 2 days ago my projects ( created via **vue create** ) stopped working - in Chrome i get

> Invalid Host Header

and

> WDS Disconnected

errors. In cmd everything compiles properly( **npm run serve** )
I don't know webpack, so i have no idea how to fix it.

What i've already done:

- reinstalled node
- deleted and reinstalled all npm packages

Answer (score 9):

This issue is caused by this webpack-dev-server [issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1604) that has been fixed recently.

To avoid getting the Invalid Host/Origin header error add this to your devServer entry on vue.config.js file:

disableHostCheck: true

Answer (score 5):

Note that `disableHostCheck: true` is **not recommended** because it creates [security vulnerabilities](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverdisablehostcheck).

For a dev server running on my local machine, I could resolve the issue by explicitly setting `--host` in `vue-cli-service serve`:

```json
scripts: {
  serve: "vue-cli-service serve --host myapp.localhost"
}
```

The `--host` option is documented [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-serve).

Visit the app in your browser under `myapp.localhost:8080` (assuming you're using default port `8080`).

Comment: disableHostCheck: true didn't work for me, but this did. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4):

Found this question searching for the same "Invalid Host Header" issue. Here's how I solved it.

I am running Vue dev server `npm run serve` in Docker on my remote server. Couldn't access it at `http://example.com:8080` with the error message above.

Correct and secure way is to add the domain name to the `vue.config.js` file:

```
"devServer": {
  "public": "example.com"
}
```

This is a fresh vue project initiated with Vue Cli command: `vue create myproject` with Vuetify added via `vue add vuetify`.  Full content of my `vue.config.js` after that is:

```
module.exports = {
  "transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ],
  "devServer": {
    "public": "example.com"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because of the dev server which isn't accepting external requests. To solve this, we've to configure `vue.config.js` as below.

If `vue.config.js` is not found in your vue project, please create the file in root directory and add the following line.

```json
module.exports = {
    // options...
    devServer: {
        disableHostCheck: true
    }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/gitpod-io/gitpod/issues/26)

Comment: This was changed (probably in Vue 2->3?), you now have to do `{ devServer.allowedHosts: 'all' }` instead. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverallowedhosts